# How can I prevent/restrict an unauthorized node from joining an an Akka cluster?

Tags: scala, akka, cluster-computing, distributed-computing, akka-cluster

In the Akka Cluster examples, documentation and tutorials, and it seems that any node can join a cluster just by knowing the cluster and the cluster's seed nodes. How can I prevent unauthorized nodes from joining?

Comment: I believe the recommended answer is: by not making your cluster a public network. Set up your security group/network in cloud provider or configure accesses on VPN network.

Comment: And is there a non-recommended answer?  I'm asking because I would like to make a public but permissioned cluster, where the permissions to join may vary dynamically.

Comment: Then probably build a permission service to safeguard the address of the Akka cluster? The logic here should be almost the same as any auth service.

Comment: You could subscribe to `ClusterDomainEvent`s and act to kick unauthorized nodes from the cluster.  This is more cure than prevention.  Beyond that, local firewall rules are generally adjustable.  You might also be able to hack Aeron into doing what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying to achieve this functionality and I also did not find this feature in Akka cluster. I managed to do by creating an authorization flag on the actor, wrap the cluster in an `Option[Cluster]`, and decide to subscribe or not subscribe the actor on the cluster in the `preStart()` mwethod. This already prevents the actor to receive messages. However, it still can send messages to the cluster members. Then I put the flag on the `case UserMessage(content) if (authorized) => ???`. I did not kik the actor out of the cluster, but I believe it is just kik he after he is up.

```
object Alice extends ChatApp("Alice", 2551, true)
object Bob extends ChatApp("Bob", 2552, true)
object Fabio extends ChatApp("Fabio", 2554, false)
```

the actor

```
class ChatActor(nickname: String, port: Int, authorized: Boolean) extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  // 1: initialize the cluster object
  val cluster: Option[Cluster] = if (authorized) Some(Cluster(context.system)) else None

  // 2: subscribe to cluster event in preStart
  override def preStart(): Unit = {
    if (authorized) {
      cluster match {
        case Some(c) => c.subscribe(
          self,
          initialStateMode = InitialStateAsEvents,
          classOf[MemberEvent]
        )
        case None => log.info(s"user [$nickname] is not authorized to enter in the cluster =(. Please leave the cluster.")
      }
    }
  }

  // 3: unsubscribe self in postStop
  override def postStop(): Unit = {
    cluster match {
      case Some(c) => c.unsubscribe(self)
      case None => log.info(s"user [$nickname] is not authorized to enter in the cluster =(.")
    }
  }

  override def receive: Receive = online(Map())

  /** chatRoom is the data structure to the users in the chat */
  def online(chatRoom: Map[String, String]): Receive = {
    case UserMessage(content) if (authorized) =>
      chatRoom.keys.foreach { address =>
        val chatActorSelection: ActorSelection = context.actorSelection(s"${address}/user/chatActor")
        chatActorSelection ! ChatMessage(nickname, content)
      }
  }
}
```